# virtualvenv issue with server output

Tags: python, flask, virtualenv

i did setup the virtuial venv on my system and i created a simple app.py ,But i cant get the see the server output which should be the webpage that displayes the app
I did as i saw the totruitals , i write "python3 app.py" and it should show up the server link but thats not happining.
`(.venv) PS C:\Users\flask> python3 app.py`

[image: this is how my vscode looks like]

Answer (score 1):

there is typo

use

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=5000)
```

once changes are made, run the program again. you will get the server running address there.